# CMake CPack debian packages

Tags: qt, cmake, debian, cpack

Has someone worked with a working example of a CPack script for debian packages with Qt and OpenGL dependencies?

I've set this one

```
set (CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_DEPENDS "libc6 (>= 2.3.1-6), libgcc1 (>= 1:3.4.2-12), libQtOpenGL (>=4.6.0), libQtCore (>=4.6.0), libQtGui (>=4.6.0), libglut (>=3.0), libICE (>=6.0), libX11 (>=6.0), libXext (>=6.0), libXmu (>=6.0), libXi (>=6.0), libstdc++ (>=6.0), libm (>=6.0), libgcc_s (>=1.0), libc (>=6.0), libGLU, libGL (>=1.0), libpthread" )
```

I googled around but never found a working example. My main problem is how to set the dependencies first for libGLU, then for libGL and the following libraries.

Once I've create the deb the installer says

```
 **Error: Dependency is not satisfiable: libXXX**
```

where XXX is one the libraries I listed before (mainly Qt libraries)

Currently my cmake version is 2.8.2 but cpack_add_component command doesn't work

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think that you can "order" the dependencies in CMake.
If you want a working example of a CMakeLists generating a .deb with qt dependencies look at :

```
project(QExhibitor)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

FIND_PACKAGE(Qt4 REQUIRED QtNetwork QtGui QtCore QtXml)
FIND_PACKAGE(CSSRobopec REQUIRED)
#Some non interesting things ...
#.....
add_executable(QExhibitor ${QT_SOURCES} ${QT_RESOURCES_CPP} ${QT_FORMS_HPP} ${QT_MOC_HPP})
target_link_libraries(QExhibitor ${QT_LIBRARIES} ${CSSRobopec_LIBRARIES})

INSTALL(TARGETS QExhibitor DESTINATION /reetiPrograms/RApplications/Applications/)
INSTALL(FILES Icons/RQExhib.png DESTINATION /reetiPrograms/RApplications/Icons)

set(CPACK_GENERATOR "DEB")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MAJOR "0")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MINOR "2")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_PATCH "0")
set(CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_DEPENDS "cssrobopec,libqt4-xml,libqt4-network,libqtgui4,treeupdatablereeti")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_DESCRIPTION "Configure UExhibitor and launch missions")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_CONTACT "Adrien BARRAL aba@robopec.com")
set(CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_CONTROL_EXTRA "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Debian/postinst")

include(CPack)
```

Answer (score 11):

You could use the [`CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_SHLIBDEPS`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/module/CPackDeb.html#variable:CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_SHLIBDEPS) CPack variable:

```
set(CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_SHLIBDEPS ON)
```

This will resolve dependencies automatically.

Comment: Thanks for this. I was looking for that option!